# how to import data from spreadsheet to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Which libraries and DLL should I use .NET to import data of Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server 2008? The library and dll should be either in C# or VB.NET or may be the code snippet will fine.

Comment: check the article link you will get your answer : dont forget to mark it as accepted if it works for u....

Answer (score 0):

Here is article that guides you how you can achieve it easily

[**Bulk Insertion of Data Using C# DataTable and SQL server OpenXML function**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/12/bulk-insertion-of-data-using-c.html)

There is no need to any extra library you just need to write following line of code to import data from excel.

```
fileName = FileUpload1.ResolveClientUrl(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
int count = 0;
DataClassesDataContext conLinq = new DataClassesDataContext("Data Source=server name;Initial Catalog=Database Name;Integrated Security=true");
try
{
   DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
   string SourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr);
   string query = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
   OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
   data.Fill(dtExcel);
   for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      try
      {
         count += conLinq.ExecuteCommand("insert into table name values(" + dtExcel.Rows[i][0] + "," + dtExcel.Rows[i][1] + ",'" + dtExcel.Rows[i][2] + "',"+dtExcel.Rows[i][3]+")");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         continue;
      }
   }
   if (count == dtExcel.Rows.Count)
   {
      <--Success Message-->
   }
   else
   {
      <--Failure Message-->
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
finally
{
}
```